# Firebase notification send to all android with php

Tags: php, firebase, push-notification

I completed the process of setting up notifications in flutter android part with firebase and when I send notification from the panel, it works without any problems.

I want to automate this with php. I tried the codes on the internet but none of them worked. I would be very happy if you could help me with this subject.

Here the code. I want to all devices

```
    <?php

 $fcmUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
 $token='token';

     $notification = [
            "title" =>"title12",
            "body" => "body of message.",
            "alert" => "Test Push Message",
            "sound" => "default",
        ];
        
        $data = [
    "title" => "This is notification title",
    "body" =>"This is notification text",
    "priority" => "high",
    "content_available" => true
];


$fcmNotification = [
    'to' => '/topics/alerts',
    'notification' => $notification,
    'data' => $data,
    'priority' => 10
];



        $headers = [
            'Authorization: key= server_key',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ];


   $fcmUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$cRequest = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cRequest, CURLOPT_URL, $fcmUrl);
curl_setopt($cRequest, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($cRequest, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($cRequest, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cRequest, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($cRequest, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fcmNotification));
$result = curl_exec($cRequest);
curl_close($cRequest);
echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For PHP you should follow this one -**
https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cloud-messaging.html

**Send multiple messages at once**
You can send up to 500 prepared messages (each message has a token, topic or condition as a target) in one go:

```
use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\CloudMessage;

$messages = [
    // Up to 500 items, either objects implementing Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\Message
    // or arrays that can be used to create valid to Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\Cloudmessage instances
];

$message = CloudMessage::new(); // Any instance of Kreait\Messaging\Message

/** @var Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\MulticastSendReport $sendReport **/
$sendReport = $messaging->sendAll($messages);
```

Notification Example

```
  use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\RawMessageFromArray;
    
    $message = new RawMessageFromArray([
            'notification' => [
                // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#notification
                'title' => 'Notification title',
                'body' => 'Notification body',
                'image' => 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/',
            ],
            'data' => [
                'key_1' => 'Value 1',
                'key_2' => 'Value 2',
            ],
            'android' => [
                // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#androidconfig
                'ttl' => '3600s',
                'priority' => 'normal',
                'notification' => [
                    'title' => '$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
                    'body' => '$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.',
                    'icon' => 'stock_ticker_update',
                    'color' => '#f45342',
                ],
            ],
            'apns' => [
                // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#apnsconfig
                'headers' => [
                    'apns-priority' => '10',
                ],
                'payload' => [
                    'aps' => [
                        'alert' => [
                            'title' => '$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
                            'body' => '$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.',
                        ],
                        'badge' => 42,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'webpush' => [
                // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#webpushconfig
                'headers' => [
                    'Urgency' => 'normal',
                ],
                'notification' => [
                    'title' => '$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
                    'body' => '$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.',
                    'icon' => 'https://my-server/icon.png',
                ],
            ],
            'fcm_options' => [
                // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#fcmoptions
                'analytics_label' => 'some-analytics-label'
            ]
        ]);
    

    $messaging->send($message);
```

**Validate the Msg**

```
try {
    $messaging->validate($message);
    // or
    $messaging->send($message, $validateOnly = true);
} catch (InvalidMessage $e) {
    print_r($e->errors());
}
```