# Firebase web push notifications to all users

Tags: php, firebase, codeigniter

hi I'm using firebase push notifications to send push notifications I'm using the CodeIgniter framework I want to send notifications to all users please help.

```
$data = [
                "notification" => [
                    "body"  => $body,
                    "title" => $title,
                    "url"   => $link,
                    "link"   => $link,
                    "image" => $imgurl,
                    "icon" => 'https://timages/favicon.ico'
                ],
                "priority" =>  "high",
                "data" => [
                    "click_action"  =>  "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
                    "id"            =>  "1",
                    "status"        =>  "done",
                    "info"          =>  [
                        "title"  => $title,
                        "url"   => $link,
                        "image"  => $imgurl,
                        "icon" => 'https://timages/favicon.ico'
                    ]
                ],
                "to" => "/topic/all"
                ];

            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            $headers = array();
            $headers[] = 'Authorization: key=< key >';
            $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Codeignighter user the Firebase PHP SDK
https://github.com/tattersoftware/codeigniter4-firebase

With refance to this documentation  - https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cloud-messaging.html

```
use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\WebPushConfig;

// Example from https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#webpush_specific_fields
$config = WebPushConfig::fromArray([
    'notification' => [
        'title' => '$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
        'body' => '$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.',
        'icon' => 'https://my-server/icon.png',
    ],
    'fcm_options' => [
        'link' => 'https://my-server/some-page',
    ],
]);

$message = $message->withWebPushConfig($config);
```

https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cloud-messaging.html#webpush

[Firebase notification send to all android with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72518196/firebase-notification-send-to-all-android-with-php/73062315#73062315)